# System hang when unplugged the external USB SSD drive

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, ssd, hardware

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on laptop, and Debian on external USB SSD drive.
My laptop hangs when I unplugged external USB SSD drive (debian).
Seems, I disconnected USB SSD drive too fast, the system didn't have enough time to end all the processes. As a result, the system hung. It stopped with text on terminal screen. I tried a few key combinations, but they didn't worked. I don't know if there is correct keys combination for cases like this. Everything was stuck, and the only way I could do was press power button until the laptop turned off.. I know this is very bad. I checked laptop HDD with `fsck`, seems it  didn't find errors. I heard such a quiet squeak when laptop turning off.. What is potential issues here for hdd for a worst-case scenario? (mainly for laptop, as it have regular HDD).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Never unplug any external USB drive without first unmounting it, and powering it off.**

- **To unmount it**, open a `Files` window, and click the up arrow next to the disks name.
- **To power it off**, open the `Disks` application, select the disk, and then select to power off this device.
- **THEN** you can unplug the disk.

At this time, I'd reconnect the external USB drive, **unmount** it, and `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb2` it.

Comment: I did by press the 'power' button until the laptop turned off.

Comment: Did you `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb2`?

Comment: Yes, I did it, the output of `fsck` show everything was OK and the result of disk check show no errors.